# Is there an alternative to installing Ruby Version Manager (RVM) from repository in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, ruby, rvm

I generally avoid the hosted Ruby repos and install RVM manually but I notice there's an RVM repo in Ubuntu Software Center now. Has anyone used it? Would I be better off continuing to install RVM manually?

I expect that, like RVM, it installs into the home directory as opposed to one that requires sudo access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I went ahead and installed **ruby-rvm** from ubuntu software center, and I can now advise **STRONGLY** against doing this.

**RVM** is supposed to install to the home directory (i.e. **home/stephen**), but the canonical hosted version installs to **/usr**, which means you need to **sudo** before you can install gems and so on.

I have removed **ruby-rvm** using **apt**, but am now unable to install **RVM** the proper way (i.e. using curl from command line) and I get an error stating that I need root privileges to write anything to **/usr**. What a joke, obviously the hosted version that I have removed, has set some kind of flag which now instructs all future rvm commands to work out of `usr/share/ruby-rvm`.

I have actually removed Ubuntu 11.10 altogether now because I just can't get used to this Unity crap. Trying Lubuntu out instead for now.